# Reverse a string by chunks

Tags: code-golf, string

Your task is to write a program which, given a number and a string, splits the string into chunks of that size and reverses them.

### Rules

Your program will receive a positive integer `n`, as well as a string `s` with length at least one consisting of only printable ASCII (not including whitespace). The string should then be split into chunks of length `n`, if the length of the string isn't divisible by `n` any leftover at the end should be considered its own chunk. Then, reverse the order of the chunks and put them together again.

### Test Cases

```
n   s           Output

2   abcdefgh    ghefcdab
3   foobarbaz   bazbarfoo
3   abcdefgh    ghdefabc
2   a           a
1   abcdefgh    hgfedcba
2   aaaaaa      aaaaaa
2   baaaab      abaaba
50  abcdefgh    abcdefgh
6   abcdefghi   ghiabcdef
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so you should aim for as few bytes as possible.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82386/42963).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
sṚ
```

A full program that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1/8cOes////JyYlp6SmpWf8NwIA)**

#### How?

```
sṚ - Main link: string, number                                   e.g. 'abcdefg', 3
s  - split string into chunks of length number (keeping any overflow) ["abc","def","g"]
 Ṛ - reverse the resulting list                                       ["g","def","abc"]
   - implicit print                                                   gdefabc
```

Comment: I like how two bytes generated 4 lines of explanation.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n:s and f(s[n:],n)+s[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#XYxBDoMgEEXXcopZQmoabdMNiScxLAYBJbGjEVe9vB2pTWNnQd5/85ktNCM@rUNIJekESA6CTC1pU5K6pFaT2cK0wBjJQySYZk@yUloU2TR5cU3zGFepRDEvkVYZ5G7b2pSwxxwqo5TabgCAtnM@9AMj9IMPnUMr7hzCNFlcLL6Y@WVmkzfnL4wsRL4Fv0FR/1WHPnjXWfxU8xzVPFnbneyhOXD7UZ3PfPkN)

Comment: How does the `and` keyword work here ? @Dennis

Comment: @ShinMigami13 empty string is not truthy so this ends the recursion

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5 4</s> 3 bytes

-1 thanks to Dennis
-1 thanks to carusocomputing

```
ôRJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8JYgr///jbgSk5JTUtPSMzIB)

```
     # Implicit: push input
 ô   # Split in pieces of length b
  RJ # Reverse and join
```

Comment: `¹` isn't needed.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```
n=>F=s=>s&&F(s.slice(n))+s.slice(0,n)
```

Takes input by currying: number first, then string, like `f(2)("abcdefgh")`.

```js
let f =
n=>F=s=>s&&F(s.slice(n))+s.slice(0,n)

let g = (n, s) => console.log(`f(${n})("${s}"): ${f(n)(s)}`)

g(2, "abcdefgh")
g(3, "foobarbaz")
g(3, "abcdefgh")
g(2, "a")
g(1, "abcdefgh")
g(2, "aaaaaa")
g(2, "baaaab")
g(50, "abcdefgh")
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>28</s>  20 bytes

```perl6
{$^b.comb($^a).reverse.join}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XU7ZTsMwEHz3V4wqCyVKSA8ED41S8Q/wiCrZzuZAzaE4rYAq/HrYuIW2rOTR7OzsrPeWcHiKTCyqT9yZJiUk41FudWSaSntyq/yoowN1lqL3pqyHkX3PPdkeCXZlTdbzo0q1axwFUK3tHN5bGviML384j3kWyEWIb7mcYCUGsefLr5wTi3anagQuNBZZ053z7zfwIOsQ0vKjj5ZMTyl8d6m0mD7r8Vxa/2oeYnbaQbK5qDMxjCsASpuUsrxgirygzKRKiwdusqbRqtPqizkjc1bc5HaFKQvCZeFSSiz/WYs8o9RodbK6OltdOVlPTJ9lbtj9uLiN@eU/)

```perl6
{[R~] $^b.comb($^a)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#XU7bSsNAFHzfrxjKIgmJ6UX0oSHFb1Df1MJek0JzoZuKWtJfjyfb2FoP7GHOzJw5u3cGHw@JSln5hRtVa4OsP7w@Hd/B1zJRdSkDvhZh15P@2BrXIsN2UxkXhEkpmiUODCiXborgTUch9edzn6akRXwW48jnQ1uwju3p4gvlpKzZigqRD02ZrXdj/u0KAXgVgzt65rMxqjUaob@0cRg@GZDOXfhHjzE57SBbXdgJ6/oFACGVNjYvCCIvjFVaSHZHg61rKXZSfBOmTpgYr1yvECSC@SxcSrD5P2uRW6OVFCerr9Hqy9NyQHKkaSD3/ew65hf/AA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣
  [R[~]] # reduce the following using the reverse meta operator `R`
         # combined with the string concatenation operator

    # `comb` with a number splits the invocant into chunks of that size
    $^b.comb($^a)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Bash + coreutils, 22

```bash
fold -$1|tac|tr -d \\n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#K8/IzElVKEpNTLFWSMnnKk4tUVAJcg3wieRKTc7IV1AxUqj5n5afk6Kgq2JYU5KYXFNSpKCbohATk/cfpIArJT8v9b@RgoJCYlJySmpaegaXMZCTlp@flFiUlFgF5sGlwOq4DDGEwADMTAKxkrhMDZCUAAA).

Comment: I've learned 4 new linux commands this week on PPCG fold is one of them, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
n#""=""
n#s=n#drop n s++take n s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcYxDoAgDAXQ3VP8tG6MzhymCkolVgLcv8Y3PTcmikSL8YjGqb8NhhHClJr/@SNqiGhdbWIFNjBI9iPl8yp6V/IP)

Comment: Pretty. It's nice when precedence works in golf

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 53 Bytes

```
<?=join(array_reverse(str_split($argv[2],$argv[1])));
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 36 bytes

```
f n{[[_]..[try head n-1]]|reverse|_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#@5@mkFcdHR0fq6cXXVJUqZCRmpiikKdrGBtbU5RallpUnFoTX/s/NzEzT6GaizM5I7GoWEMpKREIkpQ0FWoU0jSMNK0VCooy80oUlJTgKtLy85MSi5ISq6CKjLEpSkxKTklNS8/AZxCaGkMi1JgaICuq/Q8A)

It's a function that takes one argument. The characters of the string must be in the stream.

`try` is used to discard errors in case that the `head` function can't read `n-1` values.

Explanation:

```
f n{[[_]..[try head n-1]]|reverse|_}
f n{                               } /* Function declaration */
                                     /* In a loop: */
      _                              /*   Pull one value */
           try head n-1              /*   Pull n-1 values (or less) */
     [ ]..[            ]             /*   Make an array */
    [                   ]            /*   Push it to the stream */
                         |reverse    /* Reverse all values in the stream */
                                 |_  /* Flat all arrays in the stream */
                                     /* Characters in the stream are printed */
```

Not as obfuscated as usually. I think it's quite beautiful. :)

Comment: You managed to make a program less readable than the jelly solution.

Comment: Why doesn't `[[try head n]]` work instead of `[[_]..[try head n-1]]`?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Because `_` loops the expression. `[[try head n]]` would take n values *once*, but `[[_]..[try head n-1]]` takes n values as long as there are values left.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
q~/W%
```

Input is a number and a string enclosed in double quotes, separated by whitespace.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19Ypx@u@v@/kYJSYlJySmpaeoYSAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@dU6cfruoXX5v@/7@RgoKCUmJSckpqWnqGEpcxiJuWn5@UWJSUWAXlI6QhqpW4DLEJgwGUkwRiJylxmRogKwQA).

#### Explanation

```
q~   e# Read all input and evaluate: pushes a number and a string
/    e# Split string into chunks of that size. Last chunk may be
     e# smaller. Gives an array of strings
W%   e# Reverse the array. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 74 bytes

```
@if %2=="" (echo %~3)else set s=%~2&call %0 %1 "%%s:~%1%%" "%%s:~,%1%%%~3"
```

Rather annoyingly this ends up being recursive rather than tail recursive.

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
òÀ|lDÏpòÍî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3940@GGmhyXw/0FQFbv4XX//ycmJaekpqVn/DcCAA)

```
ò      ò    ' Recursively
 À|         ' Go to the "nth" column
   l        ' Move one character right (breaks loop when no more chunks)
    D       ' Delete from here to the end of the line
     Ï      ' Add a line above the current line (now contains one chunk)
      p     ' Paste the remainder of the line that was deleted
        Íî  ' Remove all newlines
```

In Action:

```
abcdefghijkl
```

turns into

```
efghijkl
abcd
```

which becomes

```
ijkl
efgh
abcd
```

before all newlines are removed

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, <s>56</s> 49 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)

```
param($n,$s)$s-split"(.{$n})"-ne''|%{$r=$_+$r};$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDhSsQwEIT/5ymWsmdatKIn@kM5uAcRjqRN2kJNayIo9vrsdS6pnOdCwuzk2yXMOHwaH1rT9wtb2tG0jMqrt5zdDYeCQxnGvvvI8tuJ3VxkpTNSHjcT@x0frtnPL@yXWeyl2BKR0lVtbNNCUtMaW9VKiwc0dhi08lp9Q@OGhhNfLkcgYaRddC4l7v@hbWNNXWmV0FgrGiva@qT0aqMB/Xh3ueZXi6c/TRe/0qVWyD2lDEi@OklH2tAkTrNIiDjgfCG2FeFDevKwrpAnOyDRyjiHW5p38MUziOxMSinm5Qc)

Comment: 1) [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVHbboMwDH3PV0TIbRINpnVTXypV6p9UCThQiQFLmFaN8u3MpJReVj9YORcfS05T/6DzBZblAJZveTc02ulPCVUMXoFPfFMe2ki@dlD1KkoqFOK06MBtYf8Crmfghp6xnWScKpbvYxfapBnavBCBFHmBNs20EWpyfQTa1rXRzuhfESA9CBL5YPsXRoi42TWtDPJUI7zIq2chRW4xS41@DAkl5pAzvPeYkTNXD@GbnPXbk20zVEzxE1/wLrjDjWPAY4NpixldH/ZnwaH/LlsilvQpUHHwgY9ATlKCX/Oc2lwGItYPfw "PowerShell – Try It Online") 2) Please, post a full program, not a codesnippet. How to check? Extract your code in a separate file with the extension `.ps1` and try calling this script instead of your code. If it works, then the test was successful.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 78 bytes

```
,<<<+[[>]>+>[[>],<[<]>+>-]<-[->>[>]>>+<<<[<]<]>>]<<<<[[<]>[-[+.[-]]+>]<[<]<<<]
```

The first byte of the input is the chunk size, given by byte value. The rest of the bytes are considered to be the string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#FYrJDcAwDMOAruO4EwhaRNCjZ7r/Aqn9EkFqDQAh0Qz2DAjNaaSS7MKoU@kKNJr7o1TsSjtKdgW81nac1/288/sB)

**Expanded and commented**

```
Read the chunk size byte
This cell will become a counter cell
,

Move left a few cells an increment; 
this is to make the starting position 
line up with the relative positioning
needed to fit in with the loop
<<<+

While the current cell is nonzero:
[

 Move right to the first zero cell
 [>]

 Move right once and increment and then move right to the counter cell
 The increment is required because of "move to zero cell" loops
 >+>

 This loop will store one chunk of the input in consecutive memory cells
 [
  [>]   Move right until a zero cell is hit
  ,     Store 1 byte of input there
  <[<]  Move back left until a zero cell (other than the current one) is hit
  >+>-  Increment the temporary cell by 1 and decrement the counter
 ] (end loop once the counter hits zero)

 Decrement the temp cell (because we needed to have 1 there initially to make the cell location work)
 <-

 Move the temp cell to three cells after the end of the chunk
 This is the new counter cell for the next chunk
 [->>[>]>>+<<<[<]<]

 Move two cells right from where the temp cell was
 This is the first cell of the chunk; if it's 0
 then the input is finished and the loop should end
 >>
]

Due to the way the counter is kept track of the tape head
will always be four cells to the right of the last input cell
when the loops breaks
<<<<

Now the chunks are printed one by one
At the start of an iteration the tape head is at the end of a chunk
[
 Locate the start of the last chunk
 [<]>

 Print the chunk:
 [
  Print the byte held in the current cell if it isn't 1
  This is necessary because we left a stray 1 in a cell at
  the start which shouldn't be printed
  -[+.[-]]+

  Move to the next cell
  >
 ]

 Move to just left of the chunk
 <[<]

 Move three cells over to the end of the next chunk
 <<<
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
""<>Reverse@Partition[Characters@#2,#,#,1,{}]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number and a string as input and returns a string as output. Not much to see here.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
s_c.*
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s_c.%2A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22abcdefgh%22%2C%202%5D%0A%5B%22foobarbaz%22%2C%203%5D%0A%5B%22abcdefgh%22%2C%203%5D%0A%5B%22a%22%2C%202%5D%0A%5B%22abcdefgh%22%2C%201%5D%0A%5B%22aaaaaa%22%2C%202%5D%0A%5B%22baaaab%22%2C%202%5D%0A%5B%22abcdefgh%22%2C%2050%5D&debug=0).

#### Explanation

```
   .*  splat implicit input
  c    split into chunks length n
 _     reverse
s      join
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Javascript - <s>54</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes**

Remade:

```
(s,n)=>s.match(eval(`/.{1,${n}}/g`)).reverse()
```

Used as

```
f=(s,n)=>s.match(eval(`/.{1,${n}}/g`)).reverse()
alert(f("abcdefgh",2));
```

Thank you to @ETHproductions for some RegEx quickenning
Thank you to @Shaggy for an extra byte in the eval!

Original:

```
(s,n)=>s.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+n+'}','g')).reverse()
```

Comment: Nice answer! I believe you can save a couple bytes by creating the regex with `eval('/.{1,'+n+'}/g')`

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah yes. That's what I've been attempting to do. I wasn't familiar enough with regex to do it though!

Comment: I think you can save a byte with currying, `s=>n=> ... `

Comment: Save a byte with `eval("/.{1,${n}}/g")`, using backticks instead of quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

### Java, <strike>147</strike> 138 Bytes

<strike>`String r(String s,int n){String r="";int l=s.length();for(int i=l/n*n;i>=0;i-=n)if(!(i>=l))r+=(i+n)>=l?s.substring(i):s.substring(i,i+n);return r;}`</strike>

Saved 9 Bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!

```
String r(String s,int n){String r="";int l=s.length(),i=l/n*n;for(;i>=0;i-=n)if(i<l)r+=i+n>=l?s.substring(i):s.substring(i,i+n);return r;}
```

In expanded form:

```
String r(String s,int n){
    String r="";
    int l=s.length(),i=l/n*n;
    for(;i>=0;i-=n)
        if(i<l)
            r+=i+n>=l?s.substring(i):s.substring(i,i+n);
    return r;
}
```

This is actually my first try to codegolf ever, so any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This is already pretty good, but there are still a few things to golf some more: `int l=s.length();for(int i=l/n*n;` can be `int l=s.length(),i=l/n*n;for(;` so you only have `int ` once. And `if(!(i>=l))` can be `if(l<i)`. And `r+=(i+n)>=l?` can be without the parenthesis: `r+=i+n>=l?`. Also, if you haven't seen it yet, I can recommend looking through [Tips for Golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) for some pretty cool golfing tips to use. :) Once again, welcome.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 38 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @LeakyNun*

```
^
 
+`(.* (1)+¶)((?<-2>.)+)
$3$1
 1+¶
```

(Note the space on the second line, and the trailing space)

This program takes input as unary on the first line, and the string on the second.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x/HpcClnaChp6WgYaipfWibpoaGvY2ukZ2eprYml4qxiiGXgiFQmOv/f0NDrsSk5JTUtPQMAA)

[Test Suite! (slightly modified)](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfx6XApZ2goaeloGGoqW2tqaFhb6NrZKenqa3JpWKsYsilYKhtzfX/v6GhdWJSckpqWnoGlyGQk5afn5RYlJRYBeYhSVkncqHxwQDESgIxkkAaSARw8wA)

#### Explanation

The first step is to prepend a space (will become important later on).

```
^
```

Now we reverse. This uses .NET's balancing groups. It is important to note that groups here act as stacks, so every match is essentially pushed onto the stack. Here we capture every digit in the unary number into group 2. Now each time a character in the string is found, a match is popped from group 2. This ensures the the number of characters does not exceed that of the unary number.

```
+`(.* (1)+¶)                       Capture the unary number in group 2
             ((?<-2>.)+)           Balancing group for substrings
$3$1                               Reverse
```

And finally remove the unary number and the newline.

```
 1+¶
```

Comment: I think it is acceptable to take the number in unary.

Comment: Anyhow, you can replace `\d` by `.` to save a byte.

Comment: The second `^` is also redundant.

Comment: @LeakyNun The program now takes input in unary, so I have no need for the `\d` anymore. And thanks for golfing away the caret :)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@doKGnZa9hqKl9aJumhoa9ja6RnZ6mtiaXirGKIZchUJTr/39DQ67EpOSU1LT0DAA) by using lazy (non-greedy) match.

Comment: [Never mind](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@doKGnZa9hqKl9aJumhoa9ja6RnZ6mtiaXirGKIZchUJTr/39DIMswOSU1LT0DAA), switch back to the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 25 bytes

Uses the `-lnM5.010` flags.

```perl
say reverse<>=~/.{1,$_}/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhKLUstag41cbOtk5fr9pQRyW@Vj/9/38jrsSk5JTUtPSMf/kFJZn5ecX/dXPyfE31DAwNAA)

Shoutout to Grinnz for telling me about `=~ m/.{1,$n}/g`

`-M5.010` enables the use of the `say` function, which for our purposes is print with a shorter name.

`-n` puts the first line of input into `$_`, and `-l` chomps off the trailing newline.

We then get the second line of input using `<>`, and apply it to the regex `.{1,$_}`: any character, between 1 and $_ (the first input) times. Since this is greedy by default, it tries to always match $_ characters. The `1,` is needed for the possible leftover chunk at the end.

The `/g` modifier gives us *every* match of that regex in the input string as a list, which is then reversed and printed. In Perl, passing a list to `say` joins it without any delimiter by default.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL Extended](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```apl
{∊⌽⍵⊂⍨(≢⍵)⍴=⍳⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG9qZv6jtgkG/9OAZPWjjq5HPXsf9W591NX0qHeFxqPORUCO5qPeLbaPejc/6t1V@/@/gpFCmoJ6YlJySmpaeoY6l4IxiJ@Wn5@UWJSUWAUTQFIA0qCjnghkGWKRUU8EAxgvCcRJUucyNUBRCwA)

Comment: You don't need the `f←`

Comment: Why, `,/` → `∊`

Comment: @Adám Oh hey that applies to my answer too, thanks

Comment: Pavel: yep, obviously.. @Adám thanks!

Comment: 14: `∊∘⌽⊢⊂⍨≢⍤⊢⍴1↑⍨⊣`

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 62 bytes

```python
lambda n,s:''.join([s[i:i+n]for i in range(0,len(s),n)][::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TcjBDoIwDADQu1/RW7dYDZB4WeKXzB062aAECtn8/@nFhHd8@flqK29xZFCqDvG@7KLGVy9OrhryXkBAFArrlExHa1JTLakN3rlbH2w7iugHshkII/9EtJf/PTpCju8x5Wk@9XDe9gU)

Comment: Python3 answer is shorter & also works for python 2.7: `f=lambda n,s:s and f(n,s[n:])+s[:n]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 9 bytes

```
#<rev''#`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#U09MSk5JTUvPUFcw@q9sU5Rapq6unPA/v7TkPwA)

`#<` chunks, `rev` reverses, and `` ''#` `` joins by empty string. Quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 24 bytes

```
:;[1,_lA|,a|Z=_sA,b,a|+Z
```

This makes excellent use of the new substring-function I recently added to QBIC:

```
:;          Read in the cmd line params a (number) and A$ (text)
[1,_lA|,a|  Set up a FOR loop: FOR b = 1; b <= A$.length; b += a
Z=          Modify Z$; Z$ is autoprinted at the end of QBIC code
_sA,b,a|    SUBSTRING: _s is the function followed by the string 
               to take from, the starting pos and the # of chars
+Z          Take chunks from further into A$, put them before Z$
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
s_cF
```

Takes input as `"s",n`: [Try it for yourself!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s_cF&input=%22abcdefgh%22%2C2&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 2 bytes

```
/¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/convex#@69/aOn///@V0vLzkxKLkhKrlP4bAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <strike>57</strike> 55 bytes

```
(n:Int,s:String)=>(""/:s.grouped(n).toSeq.reverse)(_+_)
```

Thanks Jacob! Try it [here](http://www.scala-repl.org/code/welcome).

Note: By using the symbol form of foldLeft ("/:"), I was able to take off a couple more bytes.

Comment: make it anonymous function, and use `mkString` instead of `reduceLeft`, and shave off 7 bytes: `(n:Int,s:String)=>s.grouped(n).toSeq.reverse.mkString("")`

Answer (score 2):

### C, 69 bytes

```
i;f(s,n)char*s;{i=strlen(s);for(i-=i%n;printf("%.*s",n,s+i),i;i-=n);}
```

Result is printed out to the standard output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
σ]QWJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//fHNsYLjX//9p@flJiUVJiVVcxgA)

#### Explanation

```
σ]QWJ
σ         # Split input1 into input2 pieces
 ]        # Flatten array
  Q       # Reverses stack
   W      # Wraps stack to array
    J     # Joins stack
          # Implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
∊∘⌽⊢⊂⍨⊢∘≢⍴1↑⍨⊣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FH16OOGY969j7qWvSoq@lR7woQAyjSuehR7xbDR20TwUKL/6c9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1huD5PqmBgc5A8kQD8/g/0YKaQrqiUnJKalp6RmZ6lzGIH5afn5SYlFSYpU6AA)

Explanation:

```apl
∊∘⌽⊢⊂⍨⊢∘≢⍴1↑⍨⊣ ⍝ This is a giant composed function, made of all these pieces:
               ⍝ Left argument: ⍺, the split size (refered as ⊣)
               ⍝ Right argument: ⍵, the string (refered as ⊢)
          1↑⍨⊣ ⍝ Swapped operator ↑:
               ⍝     Start with a 1, then pads with `0` until size ⍺
      ⊢∘≢      ⍝ Get the tally (≢) composed with ⊢, gives the of length ⊢
         ⍴     ⍝ Reshape the list of 1 0 0... into the size of the string:
               ⍝     As opposed to ↑, this will repeat the sequence instead of padding with 0. Gives (1 0 0 1 0 0) for a string of length 6.
   ⊢⊂⍨         ⍝ Swapped operator ⊂:
               ⍝ Split the string at all the 1s
  ⌽            ⍝ Reverse the list
∊              ⍝ Enlist, flattens
 ∘             ⍝ (composition necessary for parsing precedence)
```

---

Works similarly to @dzaima's, though it took me a lot of attempts to get there.

[¹](https://github.com/vendethiel/trying.apl/blob/master/ex/reverse-by-chunk.apl)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>69</s> 60 bytes

```r
function(s,n)cat(substring(s,(x=nchar(s):0*n)+1,x+n),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg7DoAgDADQqximVmqii4ORwwDyW6qhkHh79I2vjjidy4idfSs3gxCjtw2kO2m1cPoHXsM@2wqCxzoz6o1ezUgSHqMUjgjKOn@FmHJRtOP4AA)

Thanks to [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) for the suggestion to remove `seq`.

Comment: Looks like [this works too](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADArximViDRxcHoY6CCslRDwfB79MbLPQ6b7bEylXQziGEkVyCHF6R6KTnx@W/b7LQyXS6D4Mh6Nk2znRGNhGdXCnsE5TwdIZ5XUmbB/gE) for 66.

Comment: @KirillL. we can go to 60 bytes if we reverse the order of arguments to `:` and some manipulation lets us get rid of the trailing `-1`.

Comment: Smart, very nice!

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 78 bytes

```php
function h($n,$s){return$n>strlen($s)?$s:h($n,substr($s,$n)).substr($s,0,$n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBa4QwEIXv/oohWFRIi27pHtZuZS@FQg@FPVoPiSYqlCiJQumyv92O0a0K9TB58755E0lbtcNz0mKVvcq7ulFQ@a6irgkuWnS9Vq56MZ3@EspHL3HNwXLTc3TRoq4KgoelDUcjvg5uJ0xn4AipA5DCjoLHeF4IWVYe9cpKyLxg3MuoxY@IZdNwpjn7QY4VNTrrgU0eFfY3bNejz25GtJ2vSimKnLPNvP3G0CRWiI8GHxGqJfUU0vXSPznj/erO2v5kPbXjQBY7jmy0YHnlw/w4zKCCAC4Yb3WtOukDuYP7vcEShf/UT0UoZtIws0c0Ht/4yHbn4kJgxW7Gx6mBBMjH6XwmcADyenp7JxDEztUZfgE)

Shockingly, there's no other submission for this using recursion in PHP.  I mean, when you think PHP you think recursion, right?

**Ungolfed**

```php
function g($n, $s) {
    if ( $n > strlen( $s ) ) {
        return $s;
    } else {
        return g( $n, substr( $s, $n ) ) . substr( $s, 0, $n );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
1[&\&
0=?\i:0(?v}l&:&%
28o ]!?l~<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zBaLUaNy8DWPibTykDDvqw2R81KTZXLyCJfIVbRPqfORu///8Sk5JTUtPSM/7plCsYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 25 bytes

```ruby
~:each_slice%A|A|:~|:join
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWO-usUhOTM-KLczKTU1UdaxxrrOpqrLLyM_Mg8psLFNyijXUUlNLy85MSi5ISq5RiITILFkBoAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 32 bytes

```arturo
$=>[split.every:&&|reverse|join]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?1GrlRY)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 111 bytes

```
#import<string>
using S=std::string;S f(S s,int n){S r;for(int i=0;i<s.size();i+=n)r=s.substr(i,n)+r;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#lY2xjsIwEER7f8UqNLaIEHena7DDT6SlsROHW@myRmu7AfHtOScUUBHdNKsdvZmZNjheAicTEyOdjyLHcqBtYuoPh4epWxhkC7FGSkDq1gLrIbCcX2z2Gk3cRbx6qTRuG1LclD@7EpZYk9qyZp8yU4ndpw1S95t7DwZDIbwdj2IuGi2SVOImoGgZ70JOYEzZrqzrej@cf6oaPtXsVSeqFvKpBzmE4Cw7ey3o13v0pXSNXN99KftYIRetN7oZc/9a/t4rLe7THw)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```
n#""=""
n#s|(a,b)<-splitAt n s=n#b++a
```

Usage example: `2 # "abcdefgh"` -> `"ghefcdab"`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@nrKRkq6TEladcXKORqJOkaaNbXJCTWeJYopCnUGybp5ykrZ34PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFQcFYQVlBKTEpOSU1LT1D6T8A)

Split the input string `s` at position `n` and into `a` (first part) and `b` (second part). Return a recursive call with `b` appended by `a`. The  base case is the empty input string, where the result is also the empty string.

Note: `splitAt` returns the whole string as the first part and the empty string as the second part if the position is greater than the length of the string (`splitAt 5 "a"` -> `("a","")`).

Edit: @Ørjan Johansen saved 3 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: It's shorter to make a pattern match with `n#""=""`.

Comment: non-competing pointfree version, just for fun: `import Data.Lists;((concat.reverse).).chunk`

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 44 bytes

```matlab
@(n,s){[~,I]=sort(-ceil(find(s)/n));s(I)}{2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkadTrFkdXafjGWtbnF9UoqGbnJqZo5GWmZeiUaypn6epaV2s4alZW21U@z8xr1jDWEc9MSk5JTUtPUNdk4vrPwA)

or

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#ZZCxboQwDIb3PEU6JZZy6h2nLkVIXTrcA3SqOjghAaQoqAksRfTVqcMBQ8@L8/1/fkv28iaDSjB9/qrbV5X6OMiTsZ2Xrgu1TPAcAMokbzBPxby4imNIJWM1DsgrPrGCcy5Qm9q6phU8U9NaZ2rUomTXzK7vNUaNP9kW1IlI2@3/YQKSyL2PXuWtiEp2eQy1jbO10XiE1hJ76E6bpzPowyNccy/nh6kHzbRwtGn0A61srPduDNKpfAP5qi6wvwpQ4iMIdQaGKVk6ZZfs94hebmnFt59XAMXFe4x9fBKw/AE)

Explanation:

Example input: `s = 'abcdefgh'` and `n = 3`

```matlab
-ceil(          %round and negate
    find(s)     %generate a range from 1 to len(s)
    /n          %divide by n
    )       
       
a=-ceil([1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]/3) =
 
    a = -1  -1  -1  -2  -2  -2  -3  -3
 
[~,I] = sort(a)  %return index of sorted elements

    I = 7   8   4   5   6   1   2   3
s(I)             %sort s by I
      = ghdefabc
```

Answer (score 1):

## k, 13 bytes

```
{,/|(x,0N)#y}
```

Takes in a number `x`, and a string `y`. Splits the string `y` into a list of strings of length `x` with `(x,0N)#y`, reverses the list with `|`, and turns it into one string by folding join through the list with `,/`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 37 Bytes

```ruby
->n,s{s.scan(/.{1,#{n}}/).reverse*''}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->n,s{s.scan(/.{1,#{n}}/).reverse*''}[3,'abcdefgh']
=> "ghdefabc"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cheddar, 25 bytes

```
s->n->s.chunk(n).rev.fuse
```

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=cheddar&p=y0ktUUizVSjWtcvTtSvWS84ozcvWyNPUK0ot00srLU5VsOYqKMrMAyrSUMpIzcnJV9LUMNK0/g8A)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 75 bytes

```
$n,$r=$args;if($r-match"(.{1,$n})(.*)"){$s=&$f $n $matches.2;$s+$matches.1}
```

*I'm guessing that it may be a repeating in a some sense but it's the Recursion
** It's a few bit of fat-free version

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#XZDNbsMgEITvPAWKNjXEMapd9RRZzTv0WLfVggFHSuwKnB5q@9ldStyfdA5o5mN2JQBTDjO0W3AloLN@dzAMXHbCXjUrJoZ8C@3EmdjwFR/AlzdgKLQUYkF7UezApz8pn@aJ7BNSUEpRqlob2wRLbaONqlGSuxBM10l0Ej@CD2fwgcSb65FgA7jsor9Ckv@rNtboWkm8VKOWalTE8svJBYcQ2ve312u@PUn2o9dHrfrM9@7QWpqwhxN/YVWd8sqnrHpMudhAQjMcyZoujx/XQ/ycV2Fdd37zT/mzeMfjWf9BxYKm@RM)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 50 bytes

```
#(apply str(flatten(reverse(partition-all % %2))))
```

Just following the spec, couldn't figure how to make it any shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
×®"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///w9EPrlP7/T0xKTklNS8/I5DIGAA)

```
×®"    « input: string, integer               »;
×      « split string into chunks of integer  »;
 ®     « reverse entire stack                 »;
  "    « stringify entire stack               »;
       « implicit string output               »;
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 69 bytes

```
parse arg s,n,c
do length(s)%n+1
  parse var s b+(n) s
  c=b||c
  end
say c
```

Explanation:

1. Get arguments `s` and `n`. Given that there are only two arguments, `c` will be initialized as empty.
2. Loop for the length of `s` MOD `n` adding 1 to account for leftovers.
3. For each iteration, chop off `n` characters from beginning of `s` and store them in `b`, then append `b` to beginning of `c`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
Σ↔C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziR21TnP///6@UmJSckpqWnqH03xgA)

Takes input as two separate command-line arguments, which thanks to Husk's strong typing and overloaded builtins, [don't actually need to be in any particular order](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziR21TnP///2/0XykpEQiSlAA) since they both get fed directly into `C`, which cuts whichever one of its arguments is a list into sublists of the length given by whichever argument is a number.

```
Σ      Concatenate
 ↔     the reversed
  C    chunks of the given length of the string input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 29 bytes

My solution is almost the same as @Pavel.
Uses the `-lnM5.010` flags.
Just another 4-byte longer way to split line with **unpack** instead regexp match.
Needs one to calc penalty bytes for 3 flags?
Takes flag `M5.010` only one byte penalty?

```perl
say reverse unpack"(A$_)*",<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhKLUstag4VaE0ryAxOVtJw1ElXlNLScfG7v9/I67EpOSU1LT0jH/5BSWZ@XnF/3Vz8nxN9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 73 chars, 146 bytes

```
r←a f w;k;i;j
k←≢w⋄i←1⋄j←a⋄r←⍬
→3×⍳i>k⋄r←r,⊂w[i..k⌊j]⋄i+←a⋄j+←a⋄→2
r←∊⌽r
```

This is better because easier to write and to read... test:

```
  2 f '123'
312
 2 f 'abcdefgh'
ghefcdab
  3 f 'foobarbaz'
bazbarfoo
  2 f 'aaaaaa'
aaaaaa
  2 f 'baaaab'
abaaba
  50 f 'abcdefgh'
abcdefgh
  6  f  'abcdefghi' 
ghiabcdef
```

Comment: @dzaima now it is ok that input output

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

```apl
{0~⍨∊⊖(⌈⍺÷⍨≢⍵)⍺⍴⍵,⍺⍴0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/2qDuUe@KRx1dj7qmaTzq6XjUu@vwdpBI56JHvVs1gdxHvVuALB0Iy6D2f9qjtgmPevse9U319H/U1XxovfGjtolAXnCQM5AM8fAM/m@kkKagnpiUnJKalp6RqQ4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 101 bytes

```forth
: f >r dup i mod tuck - dup 3 pick + rot type i - -1 max r> -1 rot ?do over i + over type dup -loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BDoIwEETvfsWkV1IiGA9qgt/SAgWiZJsCRv153AUhBvfS7ZvZ2XUU@lpXTp5xPMMhCygGjwYtFeiH/AY9gQN8w58IgXr0L1@yRUMnaM0TIZNOlGtBoEcZWI3mZvJKgr4TeVx4i5ctqbBVPHGYsR06b/Ky4@kUcZDcWAE6g@LT8oDLrlPsy4vSVTUrKTgMAh2RNcGat@JT4Te@FXH/rfTflSxoKrW4MG@wAu0P3Uwf9wzHDw)

Definitely not the most golfed it could be, but this one requires more stack manipulation than usual, so it's a bit more complicated to golf.

#### Explanation

- Get `string-length % chunk-size`
- Print `string-length % chunk-size` characters starting from `addr + (string-length - (string-length % chunk-size))` [effectively, we're printing the last chunk separate, since it's size might be smaller than the chunk-size]
- Loop backwards from the start of the last chunk to the beginning of the string, printing the appropriate chunk for each iteration of the loop

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f            \ start a new word definition
  >r           \ stick chunk-size on the return stack (accessible by i)
  dup i mod    \ duplicate string-length and length%chunk-size (size of last chunk)
  tuck -       \ make copy of last-chunk-size then get last-chunk start position
  dup 3 pick + \ add last-chunk position to string address to get address of last-chunk
  rot type     \ print last-chunk
  i -          \ subtract chunk-size from last-chunk position to get second-to-last chunk position
  -1 max       \ change to -1 in case string is smaller than chunk-size
  r> -1 rot    \ move chunk-size off return stack, end loop at -1, and arrange params for loop
  ?do          \ start loop from last-chunk-pos to -1
    over i +   \ get current chunk start address
    over type  \ print current chunk
    dup        \ duplicate chunk-size
  -loop        \ subtract chunk-size from loop-index and end loop body
;              \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 74 bytes

```
	S =INPUT
	N =INPUT
S	S LEN(N) . X REM . S	:F(O)
	O =X O
O	OUTPUT =S O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNYwdbTLyA0hIvTD8YKBgr6uPpp@Gkq6ClEKAS5@gLpYE4rNw1/TS5OfwXbCAV/Ln9O/9AQoGoF22Agz9XP5f9/RydnF1c3dw9PLjMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 bytes

```
òV w
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA=&code=8lYgdw==&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoIgoy)

```
òV w     :Implicit input of string U and integer V
òV       :Split U into chunks of length V
   w     :Reverse
         :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```
&Enum.reverse Enum.chunk_every&2,&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BDoIwEETvfEWTJqBJQwSjN48ePPkJplu2lChgihj15@sWJEL3sjuzLzN4q16Vdfrg4mPT16nFJ9oO2SCU6ZvrxTvvOBdx5k7n9N4/OqbTVS4SCapAXZpkzRgvDWpVSIhmzFYkum1BWpAfgjgtEmQFUBBENzlRUOafv@Fy/syCAFNqLBTIMGCYMYWPIiDAezARpJYZu82iiE/3nNn/kcoztEbtvg)

Answer (score 1):

## q, 20 bytes

An anonymous composition of built-ins:

```
'[raze reverse@;cut]
```

Example:

```
q)'[raze reverse@;cut][2;"abcdefghi"]
"ighefcdab"
```

(equivalent to lambda `{raze reverse x cut y}`)

Comment: Where can I find an interpreter or compiler for this language?

Comment: See https://kx.com/connect-with-us/download/

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 11 bytes

```perl6
&[R~]o&comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5JboNAELzPK0oWskAQb1F8MMLyG5LckhxmacASmxgcZZH9ddKMSWynpWlVV1VXT0Ntse4PlvC@nulYlJ@Y6toQkn768nh6q3kqVe@EXUe2Q4JiX5H1g1kpmw2@BVBu7Bz@qwkD7k9/fR6zFnqLCCdvObSVOIrh1DPnxKIpZIXQhcYirdsx/24LH14VwbP86KMh3ZFB4C7tLYbf@ax7NrjSI0zOO0i2F3Yijv0KgFTaUJrlDJHllGojlbjnIa1rJVslvxhzZ8yMU25XGDIhXBYuJcXynzXPUjJaybPV1Wh15Wg1IDXSPLD7YXEb84t/AA)

Anonymous combination of two functions, `&comb`, which splits a string into chunks of size `n`, and `&[R~]`, which reverse concatenates a list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 2 bytes

```
/Ṙ
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiL+G5mCIsIiIsImZvb2JhcmJhelxuMyJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 24 bytes

```factor
[ group reverse concat ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZG9jsIwEIR7P8XiBzgdoLsCpGsRzTWIClGsnbWTgjhnO0gQ8ey5DbHFjzLdzH6alXYN6uh8v99tfzcrwBCcDmC9a5uqttB4ivHS@KqOEOivpVpTgLUQnQBWByBR6YKMLSX7BdxgNgxsSUYXqBIljXMKvcLrQC0TxZZDHk12LR9dnPEkU0kSXzYm4WTXPFOlNVRohY8uiXe9dY3hE6UGr94pTtXkxq/PTOUwXyL7auj6ThTbMRc30R/G84OnM/lAoF2tMcKx75i@P@jnhA189P8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẇr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhZLHu5qL1pSnJRcDBVYsCoxKTklNS09g8sIIgIA)

##### Explanation

```python
ẇr  # Implicit input
ẇ   # Split (input 1) into chunks of length (input 2)
 r  # Reverse the resulting list
    # Implicit output, joined
```